# SQL remove everything behind a comma in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table storing some data. One column stores strings containing a comma. I want to get rid of everything (including the comma) in this string and save it, but I don't get it to work. I tried some solutions from here but I don't understand how `substring` works in this case.
Example table data:

```
|------
|id|Name
|------
|6695|Aalen (Württemberg)
|7001|Achern (Baden)
|7133|Aach (Hegau)
|8975|Abenberg, Mittelfranken
|17223|Abbensen, Kreis Peine
|17323|Abbenrode, Kreis Braunschweig
|17608|Abbensen, Han
```

I want to get it like this:

```
|------
|id|Name
|------
|6695|Aalen (Württemberg)
|7001|Achern (Baden)
|7133|Aach (Hegau)
|8975|Abenberg
|17223|Abbensen
|17323|Abbenrode
|17608|Abbensen
```

There are about 60.000 rows, so faster solutions would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use

- [SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

and do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET mycolumn = SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn,',', 2)
```

Comment: I used `UPDATE city SET ´Name´= SUBSTRING_INDEX(´Name´,',', 2)` (Used ` in the query but the formating breaks if i do it here) on the table and it executes with no error, but nothing changes.

Comment: Also it says no rows affected.

Comment: for parameter "count" you have to use "1" instead of "2" of my example. apologies for the confusion.
note: "2" would refer to the 2nd delimiter (which you do not have according to your example).

Comment: Okay this seems to be working. Howerver the problem now is, that duplicate entries would be created and the SQL won't execute because of this. How can I avoid that? I just wan't to keep one entry and delete the other one.

Comment: Okay I solved by removing the UNIQUE key and setting it back on afterwards. Thank you!